# How do I place components on new line while contained in a <Box>?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I have all my components contained in a [`<Box>`](https://mui.com/components/box/) tag and would like to separate the submit button from the 3 text fields. I tried using a `<br />` tag and that did not work.

[Here is the website](https://brfitnessgym-93b1gfdi0-bomeers.vercel.app/bmiCalculator)

And here is the code I have:

```js
<Box
    component="form"
    noValidate
    autoComplete="off"
    display="flex"
    alignItems="center"
    justifyContent="center">

    <TextField
        label="Height (Feet)"
        id="outlined-start-adornment"
        type='number'
        sx={{ marginX: 2 }}
        InputProps={{
            startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">ft:</InputAdornment>,
        }}
    />

    <TextField
        label="Height (Feet)"
        id="outlined-start-adornment"
        type='number'
        sx={{ marginX: 2 }}
        InputProps={{
            startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">in:</InputAdornment>,
        }}
    />

    <TextField
        label="Weight"
        id="outlined-start-adornment"
        type='number'
        sx={{ marginX: 2 }}
        InputProps={{
            startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">lbs:</InputAdornment>,
        }}
    />
    <Button variant="contained" type='submit'>Submit</Button>
</Box>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply move your `Button` outside of `Box`.

```js
<Box>
  // Your inputs...
</Box>
<Button />
```

You might need to wrap everything inside a [React fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) `<> // Your code... </>`.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am trying to use it as a form. I don’t  know too much about mui forms, but does it all have to be contained in the box being used as a form?

Comment: tried the updated methods and had no luck.

Comment: It's not required to be contained in a `Box`. I just realized that you have `display: flex`, if you want to keep it that way you could simple move you `Button` outside of the `Box`.

Comment: okay great. I'll have to study up on forms now. Thank you for the help!